# A difficulty in understanding the proof of distributivity of tensor products over direct sums for modules.

Tags: modules, representation-theory, tensor-products, direct-sum

Here is the proof:

[image]
[image]

But I do not understand the following:

1-why the function needed to be bilinear to use the universal property?

2- what is he doing starting from the paragraph that starts with the statement "In the other direction ...." ?

Comment: Well the universal property is about bilinear maps, certainly to apply a theorem you need to check the hypothesese; for the second question the author is trying to find an inverse isomorphism, rather than to check that the given morphism is bijective; they do that because it's actually easier that way

Comment: @Max  .... could you please tell me a reference that defines the universal property of tensors and bilinear maps ? ....... you mean that he is trying to find an inverse isomorphism of the first one he gave in the first part of the proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The universal property of tensor product basically says that there is a one-to-one correspondence between
$$\matrix{M\times N\to T&R\text{-bilinear}\\ \hline M\otimes N\to T& R\text{-linear}} $$
maps where $M, N, T$ are arbitrary $R$-modules.

That's why for finding $(M\oplus M')\otimes N\to (M\otimes N)\oplus (M'\otimes N)$ we actually only have to define a bilinear map $(M\oplus M')\times N\to(M\otimes N)\oplus(M'\otimes N)$. 
Similarly, for the other direction, the two bilinear maps $M\times N\to(M\oplus M')\otimes N$ and $M'\times N\to (M\oplus M') \otimes N$ induce $R$-homomorphisms with domains $M\otimes N$ and $M'\otimes N$, which together induce a map from their direct sum, actually by the universal property of coproducts (and that one indeed doesn't involve bilinear maps).

Comment: For the first part of your answer (the first 6 lines) can not we do this using only part(1) of proposition (5) in Dummit and Foote third edition pg.353 , without using the universal property of tensor product? or we induce a homomorphism by the universal property ?

Comment: why we used the universal property of coproducts in the second part?

Comment: @hopefully We are trying to prove the two spaces are isomorphic. As one of them is a tensor product, you use the universal property to induce an R-linear homomorphism. Then you must construct the inverse map to actually prove they are isomorphic.

Comment: @hopefully (...) The thing is the other space is a direct sum of tensor products, that is $(M \otimes N) \oplus (M' \otimes N)$. What the answer is saying is that you first look at the R-linear homomorphism induced by $M \otimes N$ and then at the one induced by $M' \otimes N$. As you have two homomomorphism's you can use the universal property of the coproduct (in this context it is the direct sum) to define an R-linear homomorphism from $(M \otimes N) \oplus (M' \otimes N)$.

Answer (score 3):

1. In order to define maps from the tensor product of $M$ and $N$, one needs a bi-linear map $\phi:M \times N \rightarrow G$.

This is how one commonly defines a tensor product of modules via a universal property. Since $M \otimes N$ is a quotient group of $M \times N$, one needs to make sure a map from $M \otimes N \rightarrow G$ is well-defined, which is the case if there is a bilinear map $\phi:M \times N \rightarrow G$. (Wikipedia refers to the property of $\phi$ as "well-balanced").

2. The author wants to first find a map $\phi:(M\otimes M')\oplus N \rightarrow (M\otimes N) \oplus (M' \otimes N)$, and then a map $\phi^{*}:(M\otimes N) \oplus (M' \otimes N) \rightarrow (M\otimes M')\oplus N$. By defining these maps, and showing that they are inverses of each other, this makes them isomorphisms.

Comment: what is the meaning of a bilinear map? I searched Wikipedia and it gave an example of multiplication as a bilinear map, but I do not know why ..... could you please explain this for me?

Comment: why $M \otimes N$ is a quotient group of M x N?

Comment: Why the map is well defined if there is a bilinear map?

Comment: How can I show that they are inverses of each other? and how can I show thatthey are bilinear? could you please explain this?

Comment: Wikipedia has a good reference on all of your questions. If you google “Tensor product of Modules”, it’ll pull up. To show $\phi$ and $\phi^*$ are inverses, simply compose them both ways. You’ll get identity maps, which mean that they are isomorphisms in R-Mod.